# Send messages from Azure Service Bus to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus

I can see that it's possible to send messages from RabbitMQ to Azure Service Bus - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq).

Wondering if it's possible to do the reverse i.e. send messages from Azure Service Bus to RabbitMQ? Essentially trying to integrate with third party...

Comment: I am looking for similar thing. is it feasible?

Comment: this is exactly what https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/ is designed for